# How to format JTable cell with % symbol?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to set Percentage symbol in particular column in a particular row of `JTable` (note : not for all column, only a particular column).

I tried, but when I enter 10, it shows 1,000%. Can anyone give me suggestion to achieve the same?

```
public class Renderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

 private final NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

 @Override
 public final Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
 final Component result = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
 System.out.println("Value = " + value);

 if (value != null) {
     int temp = Integer.parseInt((String) value);
 setText(f.format(temp));
 }
 return result;
 }
 }
```

Comment: i think you need to use 0.1 for 10.

Comment: Does the user input the percentage symbol, or is it from your code?

Comment: your renderer is wrong, seems like as value in model too (setText(f.format(temp));), Swing JCompoent doesn't required parsing at runtime, define proper data type in model - some of number types

Comment: @milez, user can only enter the values, when they are moving from one cell to another cell, data will be show with %.

Comment: then @KDM 's answer would serve you well

Comment: Check out [Table Format Renderers](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for reusable renderers that allow you to easily create a custom renderer by simply specify the  formatting that you want. These renderers will also right align the text which is common when you use numbers.

Answer (score 1):

From the java doc of NumberFormat:

> And use getPercentInstance to get a format for displaying percentages.
>   With this format, a fraction like 0.53 is displayed as 53%

Answer (score 0):

To display the `%` symbol correctly in a string, you need to escape it by using `%%` instead.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) is a short tutorial on what is meant with escaping.